# Comparing two columns and returning adjacent column if criteria met

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 sheets, one called "data" which holds multiple columns and where I want to show the output. And one called "info" which has my comparison data.

```
id      Information
18884   Change Request
18877   Test Environmental Issue
18648   Cosmetic
17022   Data Error
17007   Requirements/Analysis Error
18664   New defect - to be determined
18864   Environmental
```

typical view of the two columns in info sheet with it being part of an external data array
"Table_ExternalData_12[id] & Table_ExternalData_12[Information]"

Within the data sheet I also have an id that is pulled from "Table_ExternalData_1[id]"
So on column K within the "data" sheet I want to say if the id matches between the two sheets then give me the information field from my "info" sheet.

```
    id      Information
    18884   Change Request
    994     
    18877   Test Environmental Issue
    18648   Cosmetic
```

How would I get this information value to populate against my id within my main sheet?

Comment: vlookup function should do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=VLOOKUP([@[bug_id]],Table_ExternalData_2,2,FALSE)
```

The [VLOOKUP function - Excel - office.microsoft.com site](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-function-HP010343011.aspx) has more details on the usage of this function.

Specifically:

> You can use the VLOOKUP function to search the first column of a range of cells, and then return a value from any cell on the same row of the range.